# How do I send parameters to a custom command in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

How do I send parameters to a custom command in Xamarin.iOS?

I want to run a custom command on Xamarin in Before Build and I want to send a parameter.
The parameter can be set on plist or another place inside the project.

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Presumably you really mean "How do I pass a parameter to a custom build command in Xamarin Studio"?

Comment: yes, correct.  And the parameter has to be somewhere inside the project. (can be on a plist or some other place)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but since it never was answered and got a few upvotes, I thought I'd take a stab.

Here is an example from [another SO question/answer about setting build date in BeforeBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37124986/510091) with a custom task in the csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AttribCommand>chmod a+w $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/BuildMetadata.cs</AttribCommand>
</PropertyGroup>
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(BuildExtensionsPath)\Foo.Framework.BuildExtensions.dll" TaskName="Foo.Framework.BuildExtensions.BuildDateTask" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="$(AttribCommand)" />
    <BuildDateTask FilePath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\BuildMetadata.cs" />
</Target>
```

Apologies if I misunderstood what was intended by "custom build command".