# Xamarin: Display version and last build time, plus auto increment version on every build

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, auto-increment, csproj

I am developing Xamarin application for iOS, using Visual Studio for Mac.

I need to display version number and last build date on the login screen. I tried to find a solution for auto incrementing and displaying version, but did not find anything that useful. As for the date, I found this solution:
[solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37124986/9815389)

But it does not work for me, since there we are running C# code, but I work on a Mac, so that code won't work, since there is no such thing as .NET Framework for Mac

I tried to include this **XML** in my csproj file of main project

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Copyright>$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("s"))</Copyright>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And this in the **C# code**

```
        var version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        BuildInfo = version.LegalCopyright;
```

This gives me correct build date, but it seems like a janky solution

What can you suggest to solve my problem? Thanks

Comment: Version info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/version-tracking?context=xamarin/android

Comment: In Xamarin IOS, you can use `NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary.ObjectForKey(new NSString("CFBundleShortVersionString"))` to get version of app.However last build date , i have no idea.